# Regex isolate and replace single white space in a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am new to using Regex, and I mostly want to use it in Notepad++ to do bulk grammar and punctuation corrections in table data.

From this string `Bonanza 1023-5 G`, I need to remove the space between the `5` and the `G`. I can't figure out how to isolate and then delete that single white space in between. There are about a dozen different ways I have found to isolate the `5 G`, but I can't figure out how to isolate that space only and not spaces before or after it in the string. This is what I am currently using to isolate the `5 G`:

```
([0-9]+([s/\s+])+[A-Z])
```

Comment: Your current question sounds as if all you need is *find* `Bonanza 1023-5 G` and *replace with* `Bonanza 1023-5G`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\h+` to match 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars and use `\K` to clear the match buffer.

```
\d-\d+\K\h+(?=[A-Z])
```

In the replacement use an empty string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xyifUc/1)

Or use 2 capturing groups and use those in the replacement using `$1$2`

```
(\d-\d+)\h+([A-Z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s8nSrt/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

Ctrl+H, select regex mode option.  Find this:

```
(\d+-\d) (\w)
```

Replace with:

```
$1$2
```

You have to find a bit right up to the space, then find the bit after the space.  These two parts need to be captured.  Then replace with $1$2 together - bang next to each other.  If you instead replaced with...

```
$1  $2
```

you'd have two spaces instead of one (as an example).

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! So simple, yet I could find nothing online to help. Still have a long way to go in learning this stuff! Thank you.

Comment: Keep fiddling and you'll level up.  @The fourth bird who provided the first answer has helped me/I'm sure knows more.  I just fiddle until I get something that works! ;o)

Comment: `\w` matches more than letters.